# How to change the error message's information and language?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

In my page I got the message lie "An error has occurred!"

The message is not fit my project.

I want to change the information and language.

I found the messages in:

---

```
\node_modules\abp-ng2-module\dist\bundles\abp-ng2-module.umd.js(353,27)  
\node_modules\abp-ng2-module\dist\bundles\abp-ng2-module.umd.min.js(1,8628)  
\node_modules\abp-ng2-module\dist\src\abpHttpInterceptor.js(33,23)
\node_modules\abp-ng2-module\dist\src\abpHttpInterceptor.js.map(1,12129) 
\node_modules\abp-ng2-module\src\abpHttpInterceptor.ts(66,19)
\node_modules\abp-web-resources\Abp\Framework\scripts\libs\abp.jquery.js(65,21)
\node_modules\abp-web-resources\Abp\Framework\scripts\libs\abp.jquery.min.js(1,841) 
\node_modules\abp-web-resources\Abp\Framework\scripts\libs\angularjs\abp.ng.js(11,23)
\node_modules\abp-web-resources\Abp\Framework\scripts\libs\angularjs\abp.ng.min.js(1,70)
```

for example
the source is

```
var AbpHttpConfiguration = /** @class */ (function () {
    function AbpHttpConfiguration(_messageService, _logService) {
        this._messageService = _messageService;
        this._logService = _logService;
        this.defaultError = {
            message: 'An error has occurred!',
            details: 'Error details were not sent by server.'
        };
        this.defaultError401 = {
            message: 'You are not authenticated!',
            details: 'You should be authenticated (sign in) in order to perform this operation.'
        };
        this.defaultError403 = {
            message: 'You are not authorized!',
            details: 'You are not allowed to perform this operation.'
        };
        this.defaultError404 = {
            message: 'Resource not found!',
            details: 'The resource requested could not be found on the server.'
        };
    }
```

**Question**:

1. I want to change the message. How can I do it?
2. I want to change the English into Chinese. Is there any set for change the message's language?

Need your help. Thanks.

Comment: Try to search `i18n` to support multi-languages

Answer (score 1):

If you are using angular, you can create a custom `httpConfigurationService` and  `httpInterceptor` based on this

https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/abp-ng2-module/tree/master/projects/abp-ng2-module/src/lib/interceptors

Your custom `httpInterceptor` should use your custom `httpConfigurationService`

Inject localization service in your custom `httpConfigurationService`

```
    constructor(
        private _messageService: MessageService,
        private _logService: LogService,
        private _localizationService: LocalizationService // to use localize error message
    ) {
    }

    defaultError = <IErrorInfo>{
        message: 'DefaultErrorMessage',
        details: 'DefaultErrorDetails.'
    };
```

And modify the `showError` to use localize message:

```
showError(error: IErrorInfo): any {

        var defaultErrorMessage = this._localizationService.localize(this.defaultError.message, AppConsts.localization.defaultLocalizationSourceName)

        if (error.details) {
            return this._messageService.error(error.details, error.message || defaultErrorMessage);
        } else {
            return this._messageService.error(error.message || defaultErrorMessage);
        }
    }
```

And modify the `root.module.ts` and `service-proxy.module.ts` to use your custom `httpInterceptor`

**Update 2:**

To only override the error message, extend the `AbpHttpConfigurationService` and override necessary properties or methods.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AppConsts } from '@shared/AppConsts';
import { AbpHttpConfigurationService, IErrorInfo, LocalizationService, LogService, MessageService } from 'abp-ng2-module';

@Injectable()
export class CustomHttpConfigurationService extends AbpHttpConfigurationService {

    constructor(
        logService: LogService,
        private messageService: MessageService,
        private _localizationService: LocalizationService
    ) {
        super(messageService, logService);
    }

    defaultError = <IErrorInfo>{
        message: 'DefaultErrorMessage',
        details: 'DefaultErrorDetails.'
    };

    // other override here...

    showError(error: IErrorInfo): any {

        var defaultErrorMessage = this._localizationService.localize(this.defaultError.message, AppConsts.localization.defaultLocalizationSourceName)

        if (error.details) {
            return this.messageService.error(error.details, error.message || defaultErrorMessage);
        } else {
            return this.messageService.error(error.message || defaultErrorMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

And in `root.module.ts`, add in the `providers`

```
{ provide: AbpHttpConfigurationService, useClass: CustomHttpConfigurationService },
```

**Update 3:**

For old version of Abp, extend `AbpHttpConfiguration` instead.

and use the following `imports`:

```
import { AbpHttpConfiguration, IErrorInfo } from '@abp/abpHttpInterceptor';
import { LogService } from '@abp/log/log.service';
import { MessageService } from '@abp/message/message.service';
import { LocalizationService } from '@abp/localization/localization.service';
```

And if it still does not work, add the provide in `service-proxy.module.ts` also.

Hope this will help. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
Do you have the sample source?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: I do have a sample code, but please try to follow my suggestions above.
You only need to add 2 files, and modify another 2 files, then come back here if you run to any issues.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Now I only want to change the message of defaultError.
Must I need to create a custom httpInterceptor?

Thank your for your help.

Comment: I am not an angular expert, but you can try to extend `AbpHttpConfigurationService` only and override the `defaultError` , `showError` and other methods to use localization.

Comment: @huhao I have updated my answer, as I said, I am not an angular expert, so please adjust it base on your needs.

Comment: Thank you answer.
I had tried 
import { LocalizationService } from '@abp/localization/localization.service';

Comment: Thank you answer.
I had tried 
   import { AbpHttpConfigurationService, IErrorInfo, LocalizationService, LogService, MessageService } from 'abp-ng2-module';
But it said there is not AbpHttpConfigurationService.
Now I tried 
import { AbpHttpConfiguration, IErrorInfo } from '@abp/abpHttpInterceptor';
export class myAbpHttpConfiguration extends AbpHttpConfiguration {
......
I Thought it is right.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: @huhao please update your question to show some code you tried and specify the issues you've encountered.

Comment: @huhao it seems that you are using an old version of Abp, may I know your version?

Comment: Thank for you answer.
I had made my source like the Update 3.
By then way, how can I get the error? 
I am not sure is it right I had made?

Thank you.

Comment: You mean, how to test if it is working?
You can throw an exception from your code to test it
`throw new UserFriendlyException("");`

Answer (score 0):

you can preload the frontend localizer and then use it(localizer), or you can override the function messages in chinese

Comment: thank you for your answer.
but how can I preload the frontend localizer ? 
and how can I override the function ? 
the messages are in the package of abp-ng2-module .

Comment: and I had set the localize for my page. for example, the log in page can show the Chinese in the label. But if I got the system error, such as defaultError, it shows English.
Need your help! Thank you